# Filling (NA values) in the column based on its previous records and another column (with interval) in R

Tags: r

I want to fill `action` column based on its records and `time` column. NA in `action` column should be filled based on previous action record and time interval. lets say we set time interval to `10`, which means that if action is `A` and time is `1`, all `NA` in `action` should be `A` till `time==11 (1+10)`.

Please note that if `action` or `ID` change, this process should be reset. For example (in row 3) we have `B` with `time==11`, I want to fill the next NAs with `B` until `time==21`, but we have `C` in `time==16`, so we continue filling NA with C until `time==26`.

```
df<-read.table(text="
id   action    time
1       A       1
1       NA      4
1       NA      9
1       B       11
1       NA      12
1       C       16
1       NA      19
1       NA      30
1       A       31
1       NA      32
2       NA      1
2       A       2
2       NA      6",header=T,stringsAsFactors = F)

Desired Result:

id   action    time
1       A       1
1       A       4
1       A       9
1       B       11
1       B       12
1       C       16
1       C       19
1       NA      30
1       A       31
1       A       32
2       NA      1
2       A       2
2       A       6
```

Comment: Seems like a case for a `data.table` rolling join: `setDT(df)`; `df[is.na(action), action := df[!is.na(action)][.SD, on = .(id, time), x.action, roll = 10]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can extract the non-NA rows to use as a reference for filling in values, then iterate through the data set and conditionally replace values based on if they meet the requirements of `id` and the time interval.

```
# Use row numbers as an index (unique Id)
df$idx <- 1:nrow(df)

# Find the non-NA rows to use a reference for imputation
idx <- df %>% 
        group_by(id) %>%
        na.omit(action)
```

The temporary data set `idx` is used as the reference and the column `idx` is our unique identifier. Let's first look at the logic for finding and filling in the missing values without worrying about the time interval, so that it's easier to read and understand:

```
# Ignoring the 'interval' limitation, we'd fill them in like this:
for(r in 1:nrow(df)){
  if(is.na(df$action[r])){
    df$action[r] <- dplyr::last(idx$action[idx$idx < df$idx[r] & idx$id == df$id[r]])
  }
}
```

If you're running this example code make sure you re-create `df` and `idx` before proceeding, since it would be modified by that last example code block.

The time interval requires us to do a logical test on the value of `time` and also another test to avoid trying to conduct the `time` comparison on NA values:

```
# Accounting for the max interval:
interval <- 10 
for(r in 1:nrow(df)){
  if(is.na(df$action[r])){
    if(!is.na(dplyr::last(idx$time[idx$idx < df$idx[r] & idx$id == df$id[r]]))){
      if(dplyr::last(idx$time[idx$idx < df$idx[r] & idx$id == df$id[r]]) + interval >= df$time[r])
        df$action[r] <- dplyr::last(idx$action[idx$idx < df$idx[r] & idx$id == df$id[r]]) 
    }
  }
}

df
```

This gives us:

> ```
>    id action time idx
> 1   1      A    1   1
> 2   1      A    4   2
> 3   1      A    9   3
> 4   1      B   11   4
> 5   1      B   12   5
> 6   1      C   16   6
> 7   1      C   19   7
> 8   1   <NA>   30   8
> 9   1      A   31   9
> 10  1      A   32  10
> 11  2   <NA>    1  11
> 12  2      A    2  12
> 13  2      A    6  13
> ```

which matches your desired output.